# Refactoring: break out class or just function to new file?

Tags: python, refactoring

When refactoring in python, what is best practice and/or more pythonic,

1. breaking out a class (like you would in Java) or
2. just breaking out the function (which you would not be able to do in Java)?

**Example:**

Let's say I have the below file

```
**large_file.py**

def large_function(x):
    # ...lots of code...
    return foo(y)

def foo(y):
    # ...lots of code...
    return function_only_called_by_foo(z)        

def function_only_called_by_foo(z):
    # ...lots of code...
    return output
```

a natural way to refactor this is to break out `foo()` and `function_only_called_by_foo()` into their own separate file. But whereas in Java I wouldn't have much choice about how to do this, I can think of two ways of doing this in python.

Alternative 1:

```
**large_file.py**

from fooer import Fooer
def large_function(x):
    # ...lots of code...
    fooer = Fooer()
    return fooer.foo(y)


**fooer.py**

class Fooer:

    def foo(y):
        # ...lots of code...
        return _function_only_called_by_foo(z)        

    def _function_only_called_by_foo(z):
        # ...lots of code...
        return output
```

Alternative 2:

```
**large_file.py**

from foo_file import foo
def large_function(x):
    # ...lots of code...
    return foo(y)


**foo_file.py**

def foo(y):
    # ...lots of code...
    return _function_only_called_by_foo(z)        

def _function_only_called_by_foo(z):
    # ...lots of code...
    return output
```

Which alternative is superior and why? (Or is there an even better option?)

None of the methods share any instance variables.

Comment: Do your `Fooer` methods actually share any state or attributes? If not, take the simpler second option. Also, consider a leading underscore to indicate "private": `_function_only_called_by_foo`

Comment: Great points, I edited my question to make the function private and to point out that no instance variables are shared.

Comment: You'll get better help at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative 2 is clearly superior - why add the overhead of the class if you aren't getting any of the benefit?

However, if you do want to go that way, consider making `Fooer`'s methods `@staticmethod`s:

```
class Fooer(object):

    @staticmethod
    def foo(x):
        ...
        return _foo_helper(x)

    @staticmethod
    def _foo_helper(x):
        ...
        return y
```

So you don't need to create an instance or have `self`/`cls` arguments you aren't using:

```
from fooer import Fooer

y = Fooer.foo(x)
```